# is there an easy way to add/delete/replace classes in asp.net cssclass

Tags: css, asp.net

I have some elements on the screen that I want to dynamically change back and forth between CSS classes "active" and "inactive". So okay, in principle I could write:

```
if active then
  foo.cssclass="active"
else
  foo.cssclass="inactive"
end if
```

But these elements have other classes on them too. I think clean coding principles would call for the function that sets active/inactive to not have to know what other classes are presently attached to that object. So what I really want is something like:

```
foo.cssclass.remove("inactive").add("active")
```

Which is a nice fantasy but CSSCLASS is a string. Is there an easy way to do this?

I suppose it would not be a tremendously challenging task to write a function that manipulates the string. So ... is there some clean, easy way to do this? Or do I have to write my own function?

Comment: Please post your actual code. What have you tried.

Comment: Afaik there's unfortunately no way to do this in a good style...*thumbs down to MS*

Comment: @maxspan I haven't tried anything. I'm asking if there's a built-in function to do this. I'm not saying I've tried the function and I'm not getting the expected results: I'm asking if there is such a function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but it should work:

```
foo.CssClass = foo.CssClass.Replace("inactive","").Trim() + " active";
```

or viceversa

```
foo.CssClass = foo.CssClass.Replace("active","").Trim() + " inactive";
```

Comment: Not quite, if I can't be sure what the present state is. Suppose cssclass already equals "foo inactive". Now I execute your second statement. I'll get "foo in inactive". And I can't search for " active ", i.e. spaces on front and back, because it may be the first or the last.